# Custom post type archive url when post type has archive string

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

Having a custom post type 'data' created by Custom post type ui plugin:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts' );
function cptui_register_my_cpts() {
    $labels = array(
        "name" => "Data",
        "singular_name" => "Data",
        );
    $args = array(
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "data", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "excerpt", "custom-fields" ),       
        "taxonomies" => array( "issue", "volume", "keywords" )
    );
    register_post_type( "data", $args );
}
```

when creating this post type using the plugin i enabled 'has archive' feature & i gave the post type archive a custom string where:

```
has_archive_string: all-data
```

I did that because it's important for me to call this post type archive using 'all-data' not 'data'. and that worked perfectly. now cpt archive is on (www.mysite.com/all-data).
But, when i tried to use wp_get_archives( $args ); to display a yearly archive links of my cpt using this code:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'data',
    'type'            => 'yearly',
    'limit'           => '',
    'format'          => 'html', 
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'show_post_count' => true,
    'echo'            => 1,
    'order'           => 'DESC'
);
wp_get_archives( $args ); ?>
```

it gives links like (www.mysite.com/data/2015) & this link leads to 'page can't be found'.
because the 2015 archive of my cpt is located at (www.mysite.com/all-data/2015) after using has_archive_string.
Please, how can i get a yearly archive links list using a code that generate the list taking in consideration has_archive_string to display a list of links like (www.mysite.com/all-data/2015) & not like (www.mysite.com/data/2015)?

Comment: custom post types were never meant to have date-based archives, that's what the built in `post` type is for. even if the generated URLs were correct, there are no rewrite rules to handle those incoming requests. search this site for `wp_get_archives` and custom post type for some possible solutions.

Comment: Hello Milo, thanks for replying. when i try to open (mysite.com/all-data/2015) it works perfectly. it displays the year 2015 archive of my cpt. my problem is about generating the archive list of links to display a list of years with this type of url. I believe there must be a solution but i still can't figure it out :(